# How to create my own annotation, nothing works

Tags: java, annotations, java-17

I'm trying to make my own getter annotation, as it is done in `lombok`:

```
package testAnns.anns;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Get {
    Access value() default Access.PUBLIC;
    Value[] method() default {};
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({})
    @interface Value {}
}
```

Tried to specify:

```
package testAnns;

import testAnns.anns.Get;

public class TestAnns {
   @Get public int l = 10;
}
```

I try to call:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestAnns ann = new TestAnns();
    System.out.println(ann.getL()); // error
}
```

Nothing works.
What to do, how to be, why does not work?
Connoisseurs, please help me figure it out, I don’t understand why it doesn’t work ...

Comment: I have a counter-question: why do you think it should work? Does Lombok provide a mechanism supporting custom annotations to generate boilerplate just like you want it to be? I haven't heard of such magic, to be honest. Also, `@lombok.Getter` does exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @terrorrussia-keeps-killing, Omg, for the sake of 1 annotation, okay 2x, load the whole library? Silly at least.

Comment: The thing that makes the lombok annotations work is the annotation processor that uses reflection to modify the compiler's AST. This is not something that can be easily replicated (and I wouldn't recommend doing that either way, since it's dependent on compiler internals). But if you're interested the source code is available: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok

Comment: @JornVernee, Yes, I already understood. It's better not to do that. Yes, and somehow suspicious, because the set and get methods can have different structures, and there a lot cannot be done without headaches. And it turns out a mess ... It's easier to create a set or get method. The experiment failed. =))

Comment: You understand that such implementation must be implemented _somewhere_. There is no such thing in JDK, and if you don't use _the whole library_, who's going to generate the boilerplate code for you? Perhaps, your code/library then, right? Even more, nothing tells _what_ the `@Get` is supposed to do, so that I was asking _why_ you think it can do the magic for you. I can't see anything silly in using a tool that does a required job: `javac` compiles the code, Lombok adds some spice to vanilla Java, _your code_ implements its job too. Note that using Lombok is **zero** cost at runtime.

Comment: @terrorrussia-keeps-killing, Well, either I will write 1 method, or I will write `@Getter`.
Again, for methods that will have a separate structure, `@Getter` does not help. This is a pointless library. It's better not to use it. It's easier to write a regular `getName()` than to write `@Getter String name;`.

Comment: Obviously, there is no magic in real life, and if the structure of your method differs and the method payload cannot be configured, auto-generated method is not what you want. Lombok or similar tools are not @Get-only "pointless" tools,. The ironical thing here is that you asked why self-coined-up-@Get-magic does not work for you, but then you say that it's easier to write the boilerplate by hands. Well, nothing to add. Good luck!

Comment: You might be better off using a `record`, e.g. `public record Test(int l) {}` gives you a `private int l;` field and a `public int l() { return l; }` accessor method *and* a `Test(int l) { this.l = l; }` constructor, as well as an `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString()` method…

Comment: @Holger, I decided not to even suffer from this when I need to do a setter and / or getter.

Comment: I don’t know what you’d suffer from when using a `record`. That’s a built-in language feature without any relationship to tools like Lombok. Of course, you can also go ahead with your own annotation approach and end up having reinvented Lombok. All for the sake of saving a few source characters. Though, I’ve seen examples on Stackoverflow, where the annotation consisted of more code than the generated feature would have needed when written manually…